# How to write a constant turn motion model for multiple objects(>2)?

Tags: circular-motion

I am working on multiple object tracking. The next state of a state variable given the current state is characterized by the equation $x(k+1) = Fx(k) + noise$. $F$ is a state motion model matrix. It models the motion of state variable $x$. For a state variable $x$, with entries$[x_1, \dot{x_1}, x_2, \dot{x_2}]$, $x_1$ is the position and $\dot{x_1}$ is the velocity for measurement 1. Similarly, $x_2$ and $\dot{x_2}$ are position and velocity respectively for measurement 2. If the motion is modeled as constant velocity (CV), then $F$ is given as

$$
F_{\textrm{CV}} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & T & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & T \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.\tag{1}
$$

Likewise, if the motion is modeled as constant turn (CT) model, the CT matrix is given as

$$
F_{\textrm{CT}} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \frac{\sin \omega T}{\omega} & 0 & -\frac{1-\cos \omega T}{\omega} \\
0 & \cos \omega T & 0 & -\sin \omega T \\
0 & \frac{1 - \cos \omega T}{\omega} & 1 & \frac{\sin \omega T}{\omega} \\
0 & \sin \omega T & 0 & \cos \omega T
\end{bmatrix}.\tag{2}
$$

These are characterized by laws of motion. But if there are more than 2 measurements, I can simply write the CV matrix as

$$
F_{\textrm{CV}} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & T & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & T & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & T \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\tag{3}.
$$

But how can we extend the CT model for multiple measurements? I think unlike CV model, CT model entries are non zero for other measurements. So I cannot simply add zeroes just like I did in (3). Please help me understand this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.